# How do you pass an instance of a class as an argument for a method of that class?

Tags: java, class, parameters, arguments, instance

Let's say I have this code. When using an instance of ClassA, how do I pass the instance of the class to the method `methodA`?

```
public class ClassA {

    public static int methodA(ClassA class) {

        return 1;
    }
}
```

---

```
//This is wrong but this is what I'm trying to do
public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        ClassA classa = new ClassA();
        classa.methodA(classa);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to achieve this is correct. Just use another name, because `class` is a reserved keyword for class definition

```
public static int methodA(ClassA instance) {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to call methodA from methodB, also inside that class? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @kryz and doe methodB looks like ?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach works but you must not use the keyword `class` as a variable name. Try

```
public class ClassA {
    public static int methodA(ClassA clazz) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```